# mainStoryBoard , source code mode

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, xcode4.2

I have an app that is TAB BAR CONTROLLER, in the first and in the last tab it has another TAB BAR CONTROLLER, I'm trying to add title and image.

I have no problem with the first one, but I have with the last one. I think is the image, I wrote:

```
<tabBarItem key="tabBarItem" title="Stations" image="ico_paradas.png" id="J2M-ix-HLu"/>
```

It works, this is the first one.

the last one:

```
<tabBarItem key="tabBarItem" title="Info" image="ico_info.png" id="hnR-0m-dE0"/>
```

it made a mistake:

```
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 255
```

But if I change the image value for another one, it works.

I also check the image, and add it to another tab, with mainStoryBoard in graphic mode, and it works, it just doesn't work when I add it from source code, I cant add it whith the graphic mode because is a TAB BAR CONTROLLER into a TAB BAR CONTROLLER.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Subclass your tab bar controller and set its title and image programmatically. Using storyboard source code is pretty much never a good idea.